# What's the difference/connection between the SVN and GIT repos of FreePascal/Lazarus

Tags: svn, git, lazarus, repository, freepascal

I've been updating from the SVN repo from the main page, but also found the GIT repo on github.

Are they connected or should I use one more than the other?

Where is the fpbuild and fpprojects on github that exist on the SVN repos?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently FPC only uses Subversion.

There are some experiments with git by 3rd party parties (some mirroring, some forking for the development of radical features), but that is not official.

There also existed (still?) a Mercurial mirror for the same reasons.

So, in short, use SVN, and SVN only unless you know what you are doing.